# Div sendo sobreposta por outra

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap

Estou ajustando a versão mobile de uma página, utilizando o bootstrap eu defini minhas divs com as classes col-md-4 (versão desktop) col-xs-6 (versão mobile). Na versão desktop está funcionando normal com três colunas como preciso, já na versão mobile (de duas colunas) as divs estão sendo sobre postas umas pelas outras.
[image: Versão Desktop]

[image: Versão Mobile]

O código está mais ou menos assim:

```css
.blocos
          {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            .icone
            {
              margin-top: 20%;
              @media screen and (max-width: $smartphone)
              {
                width: 80px;
                display: block;
                float: none;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-top: 0;
                img
                {
                  margin-top: 30%;
                }
              }
            }
.col-xs-6
          {
            @media screen and (max-width: $smartphone)
            {
              height: 200px;
              margin-top: 0;
              margin-bottom: 15px;
              top: 0;
            }
          }
          .col-md-4
          {
            background-position: top center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            height: 500px;
            margin-top: 30px;
            max-width: 425px;
            @media screen and (max-width: $smartphone)
            {
              height: 200px;
            }
          }
          .middle
          {
            margin-left: 35px;
            @media screen and (max-width: $smartphone)
            {
              margin-left: 0;
            }
          }
          .right
          {
            float:right;
            @media screen and (max-width: $smartphone)
            {
              float: none;
            }
          }
```

```html
<div class="row blocos">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
    <!--Conteudo.....-->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
    <!--Conteudo.....-->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
    <!--Conteudo.....-->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
    <!--Conteudo.....-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente, errei desde o início, tive um trabalho árduo para fazer manualmente o que o CSS3 faz automaticamente!

Recomendo este artigo:
http://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/css/flexbox/

O uso de FlexBox facilita, e muito, na hora de montar um layout responsivo!

Comment: fique atento a compatibilidade das flexbox, para mim é o melhor método de desenvolvimento de layout, mas deixa a desejar em compatibilidade, por isso uso ele junto com angular material que fornece elas como diretivas sem se preocupar com prefixagem entre navegadores